# Retrieving Variable & Processing List from Tastypie URL

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Let's say my override_urls is like so:

```
def override_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<user__username>\w{4,30})%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('dispatch_list'), name="api_dispatch_list"),
        ]
```

I'd like to do some custom processing owith user__username: I'd like to get all of a user's 'post' objects and combine it with everyone they follow's post objects.

How can I nab user__username for get_object_list to process? I tried to get it from the request using request.GET.get('user__username') but that didn't seem to make sense (and didn't work).

PS, is there anyway to make user__username into just username (for the sake of prettyness)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user_username argument is passed in kwargs through the dispatching process not in request.GET.

You probably would want to override the
[get_list method](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1116) and process the additional argument inside it. If you do it that way you can name your argument whatever you want and process it the way you wish.